# Set intersection of object dropping keys

Tags: python, set

I'm trying to perform some set operations using this object.

```
def Group(object):
  def __init__(self, name, email, description, skip_if_deleted, membership=None)
    self.name = name
    self.email = remove_special_characters(email.lower(), bad_chars)
    self.description = description
    self.action = None
    self.skip_if_deleted = skip_if_deleted
    if membership is not None:
      self.membership = set(membership)
    else:
      self.membership = set([])

  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.email)

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.email == other.email
```

I am finding that when doing set intersections, I seem to be dropping the populated key 'membership', in exchange for an empty one.

An example:

Fetch from the first source, which does not provide membership information at time of fetch

```
# Example obj in unpopulated_membership looks like: Group(name, email, description, membership = empty set)
unpopulated_membership = set(get_groups_from_first_source())
```

Fetch from the second source, which does return membership information

```
# Example obj in populated_membershop looks like: Group(name, email, description, membership = populated set)
populated_membership = set(get_groups_from_other_source())

common_groups = populated_membership.intersection(unpopulated_membership)
```

Now at this point, common groups gives us the commonalities between the two sets, but the key 'membership' is now equal to `unpopulated_membership's` value. Regardless of whether i do populated_membership.intersection() or unpopulated_membership.intersection()

Why is this? How can i retain the membership information found in `populated_membership` when performing this intersection?

Thanks!

Comment: If you care which of two `Group` objects with equal `email`s you keep, you shouldn't be defining `__hash__` and `__eq__` based on `email`.

Comment: To second @user2357112, you also shouldn't be using a `set` if you care which one is kept. It sounds more like you want some kind of data merge operation than to eliminate dupes, and that's going to require some custom code.

Answer (score 1):

The quick-fix would be to use a set comprehension:

```
common_groups = {group for group in populated_membership
                       if group in unpopulated_membership}
```

I would recommend choosing a different way to represent your data, though. For example, using dicts to match email addresses with the information associated with them. You've defined your `Group.__hash__` and `Group.__eq__` in such a way that "equal" Groups hold different data, which is highly unusual.

Also, if this is Python 2, don't forget to define `__ne__`. You should also define `__eq__` and `__ne__` in such a way that they return `NotImplemented` instead of throwing an `AttributeError` when the other object isn't a Group.